# Overwatch league - Draws in playoffs

Tags: overwatch, competitive-gaming

In OWL, you can get draws on maps (if both teams got the same number of control points, but no time in the bank)

In the normal season, that works because there are 4 maps scheduled, with a 5th tiebreaker map at the end, if the series end 2-2.

But it just happenned in the playoffs, where all 5 maps are already decided (map 3 of NY vs BOS was tied, opening the way to the score being 2-2 after 5 maps)

So what would be to happen if, after 5 maps in the playoffs, the score was 2-2? In playoffs you cant just let it be as a tie, a winner must be decided and I didnt hear anything about a tiebreaker map 6 if necessary.

Didn't happen this time, NY won map 4 to win the series 3-0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it comes to a 2-2 situation in a playoff match, a 6th map will be played.

It was mentioned in the live stream of that very match by Semmler, starting at about 30s in the VOD.

Season 1, Stage 3 Playoffs, NYX-BOS: https://overwatchleague.com/en-en/match/10545/game/10297